# Fetch Values from NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: ios, twitter, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting response from Twitter Response using FHSTwitterEngine.

[Code Output](http://pastie.org/8947166)

How can I get username and name key values. as I try this

```
                    self.screenName = [dicUser objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
```

It gives error.

```
[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcca78b0
```

Comment: Read the message.  You've got an array, not a dictionary.

Comment: `...[2546:80b] My Dict is (` -- See the `(` character?  That indicates an array.  If it were a dictionary you'd have `{`.

Comment: Note that copying code examples for parsing JSON hardly ever works, since different sites transmit entirely different JSON structures.  Go to json.org and learn how to actually read and understand the JSON.  (It only takes 5 minutes.)  The NSLog dump of the iOS arrays/dictionaries of the parsed JSON is nearly the same except that `()` is used instead of `[]`.

Comment: You should use as like this to get screen_name from your response array: self.screenName = [[[dicUser objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"screen_name"];

Comment: Except that if you use what @Natarajan suggests you will never understand what you're doing.

Comment: self.screenName = [[dicUser ValueForKey:@"screen_name"] objectAtindex:Index];

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the return value is an `NSDictionary` when in fact it is an `NSArray`. Protect yourself from crashing by wrapping your call with:

```
if ([dicUser isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
{

}
```

Comment: means NSDictionaries are within NSArray?

Comment: I have no idea what the internal structure is, but the root is an NSArray. Try printing it out using nslog or the debugger to learn more.